# How can I ride my Pseudodragon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, familiars, mount

I play a tiny sorcerer with a Pseudodragon familiar, I'd like to be able to ride it, but we are both tiny.

We play d&d 3/3.5 mixed (whatever rules end up being more convienent).

The best route seems to be to find a way to enlarge it, if I could make it small I could ride it. Animal-growth spell won't work since dragons aren't animals.

If there's no way to enlarge it, are there any spells/objects that would help me ride it reliably? My understanding is that there is no hard rule stating that you must be the 1 size smaller than something to ride that thing. So I *think* I could ride it unreliably as an "ill suited mount" and take a penalty.

I'm willing to spend money time and feats to make this happen (I'm level 13).

Comment: What Tiny race is the pilot?

Answer (score 23):

With the extremely obscure feat: "Mighty Steed". Found in the [mount handbook](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=25.0), the handbook states:

> Mighty Steed: A feat found in the Dragonlance supplements Bestiary of Krynn and Knightly Orders of Ansalon. A mount with this feat counts as one size category larger for determining carrying capacity and the minimum size of its rider. That is, it lets a Medium character ride a Medium mount, and lets a kobold with Slight Build ride a pseudodragon.

The undersized mount feat (for the rider) is found in pathfinder and does a similar thing.

Comment: Wait, so both feats in combination would let you ride a mount smaller than yourself? "Go forth, Mr. Fuzzykins! Carry me to victory!"

Comment: Yes. That is the theory (so long as the mount has sufficient strength and the DM doesn't throw dice at you.)

Comment: I shall have to buy Mr. Fuzzykins a new *collar of giant strength*, then.

Comment: Those two feats are so awesome together that I can't even find words to describe. I will definitely build a villain around this.

Answer (score 8):

I am suggesting a different route to achieve your goal:

**Reduce Yourself**

Going to be diminutive will change your gameplay, but will also open a lot of new opportunities. **Reduce Person** is obviously the key here if you are Humanoid, and it can be made permanent too for a small fee at your level. For non-humanoid races, **Alter Self** will probably do the trick.

If permanency seems too radical, or if you are not Humanoid, the **Ring of Reduction** from *Lords of Madness* will grant at will reduction for 20k and it works for every intelligent creature. Other objects like Belt of Growt from *MIC* can be proposed to your DM to be houseruled as a reduction version / race specific.

As a sidenote, getting equipment like Riding Boots / Battle Bridle and Military Saddle will make your riding life a lot easier (and safer) while flying.

Answer (score 6):

Your share spells class feature allows you to cast spells with Target: You on your familiar (as Range: Touch).  *Alter Self* is such a spell, and allows your Pseudodragon to turn into any Dragon-type creature from Diminutive to Small size.  A Wyrmling Green Dragon (among other wyrmling dragons) is such a creature, and is of small size.  You can either cast the spell as necessary (a 13th level spellcaster shouldn't have too much trouble with this) or get an item that allows your dragon companion to use it themselves (which they will enjoy to no end.  Be careful with those breath weapons, though: even at 2d6 those things are dangerous in the hands of a mischievous pseudodragon).

Comment: ...Which breath weapon is provided in 3.5 via [*alter self*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#alter-self "dndsrd.net alter-self entry")?