# How does the rider's shape affect the ride skill?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, races

The [ride](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#ride) skill mentions that a creature ill-suited to be a mount imposes a -5 penalty to any ride checks while riding it, but what about the rider's suitability to ride a creature?

For example, what if a bariaur (a medium sized centaur-like being from the *Planar Handbook* p7-8) wanted to ride a horse or dragon? Would it have the listed penalties, no penalties, or even other penalties?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, "a creature ill-suited to be a mount imposes a -5 penalty to any ride checks while riding it".

A creature can be ill-suited for any number of reasons including the size/shape of the rider.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Yep, and Dale is saying that a horse is unsuited to be a bariaur's mount, even if it's suited for being a human's mount.

Comment: Are you saying that either "...ill-suited to be a mount [for you] imposes..." or "...ill-suited to be [your] mount imposes..." are implied? Or are you just saying that the clause is generic enough that an untrained mount, a poorly shaped mount, and a frail mount all count as 'ill suited'? *Not* arguing/detracting, just clarifying.

Comment: This begs the question: If I wanted to ride a squirrel, would it still be only a -5? XD EDIT This actually has an answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56217/how-can-i-ride-my-pseudodragon?rq=1